# Should I make all class variables part of state?

Tags: reactjs

Say I have a class variable which I know won't change but is still needed to render the component. Something like this perhaps:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        let { arrayOfImages } = this.props;
        this.arrayOfImages = arrayOfImages;
        this.state = {
            colorOfBackground: 'blue'
        };
    }

    render() {
        let images = this.arrayOfImages.map(image => {
            return <img src={image.src} />
        });
        return (
            <div style={{color: this.state.colorOfBackground}}>
                {images}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Is it better to just make the `arrayOfImages` part of the state or just keep it as a class variable?

Answer (score 0):

No, It is not necessary to put `arrayOfImages` in `state` if this will not change. It is better to put those value in `state` which can be change and want to re-execute code every time or conditionally when it change.